# How to declare an array of structs located in memory

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, hook, ida

Using IDA Pro I have located some array in memory that is a struct array and now I need to declare it it in my code so I can use it to read and write values.

```
struct SomeStruc{
  bool bSimpleBoolean;
  BYTE nByteValue;
};

// I have already hooked into process and have access to memory.
SomeStruc *someArray = (SomeStruc *)0x<ADDRESS_HERE>;

// 45 is size of array, let's say.
for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
  printf("%i %i", someArray[i].bSimpleBoolean, someArray[i].nByteValue);
}
```

The problem with that is that it doesn't work. Please, tell me where I wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: In which way does it not work? Please give more details.

Comment: `_someArray[i]->bSimpleBoolean` -> `_someArray[i].bSimpleBoolean`

Comment: How can IDA give you an absolute address? I doubt that address is the same when a new process is starded.

Comment: The actual address is most probably different. Read about address space randomization.

Comment: I am sure that address is correct - it's static. Accessing using construction I wrote just gives me zeroe's.

Comment: You could have alignment/padding issues if you expect the bytes to be packed.  Also, you call your variable _someArray, which is a reserved name in global namespace (as are all names starting with underscore.)

Comment: I have tried to change a name but it doesn't help.

Comment: In which way does it not work? Compiler error? Runtime misbehaviour? Crash? Segfault? Please give more details. And please edit your question to fix your typo.

Comment: Sorry, edited the question. It gives me zero's instead of values.

Comment: And what makes you think that zeros would not be the right values?

Comment: Because I know that program that I'm hooked into is using this array and it has values in it.

Comment: If you have access to the correct value (maybe some kind of debugger memory view) then you might make the risky experimetn to write to the byte value and booleans, instead of reading. If the written values do not appear at the correct places, your mapping is wrong.

Comment: Are you aware that the address your code is writing to is most likely a virtual address? If your are sure that the address you are using is static and reproducebly identical, then it is likely to be a physical address, or a virtual address in a different address space (e.g. as seen from a different process). Any of that will cause the same "number" used as an address hitting a different part of memory than what you are looking at.

Comment: And how do I point to a correct address? I have attached to a process using IDA and jumped to that address - it's an array of structures as I described with correct values (not zero) in it. But I still get 0 insted of actual values. :(

Comment: What's architecture? How you building your code? Explain what do you mean by "have access to memory" - you use something like CreateRemoteThread (if you arch is Windows) or ReadProcessMemory? Have you tried 'printf("%d\n", sizeof(SomeStruc));`?